# raise AttributeError("move_to requires a WebElement") AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement

Tags: python, selenium

In this program I need to scroll down and click the particular element to view more products. In my case I can able to scroll down and I have clicked the 1st element to view more products but I'm unable to click the 2nd element in the website to view more products. please me help on this.

website: https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone_ct-VHJvbnktQjJDLVRyb255fHx8MzE5OQ

```
import xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time
from datetime import date
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class tronymobiles:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url='https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone_ct-VHJvbnktQjJDLVRyb255fHx8MzE5OQ'       
        self.country='IT'
        self.currency='euro'
        self.VAT='Included'
    def trony(self):
        #try:
            wb = xlwt.Workbook()
            ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
            ws.write(0,0,"Product_Url")
            ws.write(0,0,"Product_Manufacturer")
            ws.write(0,1,"Product_Url")
            ws.write(0,2,"Product_Price")
            ws.write(0,3,"Product_Model")
            ws.write(0,4,"Memory")
            ws.write(0,5,"Currency")
            ws.write(0,6,"Color")
            ws.write(0,7,"VAT")
            ws.write(0,8,"Shipping Cost")
            ws.write(0,9,"Pre-PromotionPrice")
            ws.write(0,10,"Country")
            ws.write(0,11,"Date")
            ws.write(0,12,"Raw_Model")
            wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\trony.xls")
            driver=webdriver.Chrome()            
            driver.get(self.url)
            today = date.today()            
            driver.maximize_window()
            time.sleep(3)
            overlay_close_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="kor-overlay-close kor-control"]')         
            overlay_close_button.click()
            try:
                time.sleep(3)
                cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'ACCETTO')]")
                time.sleep(3)
                cookies.click()
                print("Accepted cookies")
            except:
                pass
            initial_val=0
            s=3000
            while s<=15000:
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo({},{});".format(initial_val,s))
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")))
                time.sleep(4)
                element12 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")#.click()
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12).click().perform();
                print(s)        
                initial_val=s
                s+=3000
                time.sleep(5)
            while True:             
                containers = []
                containers =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="smcc-listing-risultati-prodotto container-fluid false"]')                 
                for container in containers:                      
                    #try:
                        url = container.find_element_by_css_selector('.listing_risultati_prodotto_2')
                        urls = url.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                        print(urls)

                        title = container.find_element_by_css_selector('.listing_risultati_prodotto_2').text
                        print(title)
                    #except:
                        #pass
                break
        #except:
            #pass      
trony_it=tronymobiles()
trony_it.trony()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLCpR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `move_to_element` you are passing `element12` which is a list since it usage `find_elements`

see this line there

```
element12 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")#.click()
```

to fix this error, either use `find_element`

**like this :-**

```
element12 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")#.click()
```

or in  `move_to_element` pass the list index.

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12[0]).click().perform();
```

I have passed `0` as an args which should be first element of the list, if you want anything specific feel free to pass the desired index.

**Updated 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone_ct-VHJvbnktQjJDLVRyb255fHx8MzE5OQ")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick='acceptCookies();']"))).click()
except:
    pass

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='kor-overlay-close']"))).click()
except:
    pass

pagination_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ish-pagination-total-value"))).text
pagination = int(pagination_value.split(' ')[0])
number_of_product_per_pages = 12
to_scroll_till_end_count = int(pagination/number_of_product_per_pages)

lnght = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'listing-risultati-prodotto ')]/div"))

for a in range(to_scroll_till_end_count):
    j = 0
    k = 1
    for i in range(lnght):
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'listing-risultati-prodotto ')]/div")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elements[j])
        product_name = elements[j].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::a[@class='listing_risultati_prodotto_2']")
        print(product_name.text)
        product_link = elements[j].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::a[@class='listing_risultati_prodotto_2']").get_attribute('href')
        print(product_link)
        product_price = elements[j].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::span[contains(@class,'ish-priceContainer-salePrice-value')]").get_attribute('innerText')
        print(product_price)
        j = j + 1
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
    time.sleep(4)
    show_more = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"(//div[contains(@class,'ShowMoreProductsEnt')])[{k}]")))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(show_more).click().perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    k = k + 1
```

**Output :**

```
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
ALCATEL Alcatel 1B
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-alcatel-1b_sku-2210005236
75,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) LIGHT BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-light-blue_sku-2210004388
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610) DARK BLUE
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610-dark-blue_sku-2210004383
79,00 €
WIKO Y62 (W-K610)
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y62-w-k610_sku-2210004391
85,00 €
WIKO Y81DEEPBLUENEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81deepbluenew_sku-2210004385
89,00 €
WIKO Y81GREENNEW
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-y81greennew_sku-2210004373
89,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005206
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1SE LITE EDITION
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1se-lite-edition_sku-2210005205
99,00 €
WIKO View4 Lite
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/wiko-view4-lite_sku-2200002239
99,00 €
MOTOROLA MOTO E6I
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/motorola-moto-e6i_sku-2210001745
99,00 €
TIM MOTOROLA moto e7i POWER
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/tim-motorola-moto-e7i-power_sku-2210003644
99,00 €
ALCATEL 1S 2021
https://www.trony.it/online/telefonia/smartphone-cellulari/smartphone/alcatel-1s-2021_sku-2210005208
112,95 €
```

Comment: ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12[0]).click().perform();
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable  
I'm getting error like this.

Comment: what is the size of the list ?

Comment: also I have mentioned `element12 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")` as well, to use `find_element`, did you do that ?  did that also fail ?

Comment: the size of the list 11

Comment: See declare `element12` like this `element12 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")` and then use this : `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12).click().perform();`

Comment: element12 = element12 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12[0]).click().perform();
using this code i can able to click 1st element but can't able to click the 2nd element.
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12[1]).click().perform();

Comment: I have updated the code above, do check it out and let me know if that works, also don't forget to copy `j`.

Comment: element12 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12).click().perform(); 
i used this i can be able click only one element I'm unable to click 2nd element

Comment: Okay try updated 1 code above, I think you need to scroll till end right to click on the 2nd element  ?if so, please use updated 1 code above

Comment: It didn't work, but thank you so much for your support and efforts u have given.

Comment: for second click, it has to scroll till end of the page ? also can you tell me what data you want to scrape from the mentioned web site ?

Comment: i need to click till end there are 11 elements.........i want to scrape product name, product link and price of the product

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things here

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")
```

returns a list of web elements, not a single web element object.

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12).click().perform();
```

requires a web element object passed to `move_to_element()`.
In order to make this working you can pass there a first element in the list, like this

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12[0]).click().perform();
```

Alternatively you can change

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")
```

to be

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")
```

in this case

```
element12 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'container-link ShowMoreProductsEnt')]")
```

`element12` will be a web element and will be able to pass it as is to

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12).click().perform();
```